# Facebook Social Plugins Like button returns "Website Inaccessible"

Tags: facebook, plugins, facebook-like

We've just added Facebook like button to http://www.willyoung.co.uk/global/songs-and-lyrics/releases/the_hits?page=1, however the json returned by facebook is

```
for (;;);{"error":0,"errorSummary":"","errorDescription":"","errorIsWarning":false,"silentError":0,"payload":{"requires_login":false,"success":false,"already_connected":false,"is_admin":false,"show_error":true,"error_info":{"brief":"Website inaccessible","full":"The page at http:\/\/www.willyoung.co.uk\/global\/songs-and-lyrics\/releases\/the_hits could not be reached."}}}
```

It basically says that the website is not accessible. We've implemented this on other sites and it's fine. I'm not really sure where this is coming from. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add "/" at the end of the URL:
http://www.willyoung.co.uk/global/songs-and-lyrics/releases/the_hits/

Then it should work.

Comment: I've seen this error most frequently when the href (or actual page URL) is fine, but there's a <og:url> tag with a similar but slightly incorrect URL - this can be hard to debug because the linter doesn't explain precisely where the 'inaccessible' URL originated

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, adding the url parameter worked for me

```
<fb:comments url="your_url"></fb:comments>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same problem today.  The solution involved using this page: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint until it was clean.

My case was a simple typo, I had put http://mymagicfblikebuttom.com instead of http://mymagicfblikebutton.com (the last letter of "button" was an "m" instead of an "n").

I took the URL that linter was complaining about, pasted into the URL of the browser, and sure enough, it could not be found.

Then I bounced FireFox, then actually found another error in the "lint" or "linter" utility (the graphic name also had the misspelled domain name, bounced FireFox again, then it worked.